# Second order nonhomogeneous problem with wronskian

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second order nonhomogeneous differential equation:

$$x^2y''-3xy'+4y= \ln(x)$$

I'm stuck at finding the solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

Are my $y_1,y_2$ true? Or is my determinant false in my following attempt:

First I found solution for the homogeneous equation, it is a repeated root so

$$y_p=Ax^2\ln(x)+Bx^2$$

Here for the nonhomogenous equation, I used parameter variation:

$y_1= x^2 \ln x$ and $y_2=x^2$

Using Wronski and Cramer rules:

$y_p=u_1.y_1+u_2.y_2$

$W= \det\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
    x^2 \ln x & x^2 \\
     2x \ln x+x & 2x
  \end{array} \right]=-x^3$

$W_1= \det \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & x^2 \\
     \ln x & 2x
  \end{array} \right]$
$=-x^2 \ln x$

$W_2= \det \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     x^2 \ln x & 0 \\
     2x \ln x+x & \ln x
  \end{array} \right]$
$=x^2 \ln^2x$ 
$u'=\frac{W_1}{W}=\frac{-x^2 \ln x}{-x^3}=\frac{\ln x}{x}$
$u'=\frac{W_2}{W}=\frac{x^2 \ln^2x}{-x^3}=\frac{-\ln^2x}{x}$

Integrate to find  $u_1, u_2$

$u_1=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2x$

$u_2=-\frac{1}{3}\ln^3x$

$y_p=u_1.y_1+u_2.y_2 =\frac{1}{2} \ln^2x$$.x^2 \ln x$ $-\frac{1}{3}\ln^3x$ $.x^2$

$=\frac{1}{6}x^2 \ln^3 x$ 

 Is this right???

However the book said that the answer is $y=x^2(A \ln x+B)+\frac{1}{4}(\ln x+1)$

Why is this not the same??

Comment: Take a look at the corrections I have brought to your text. In particular, a Wronskian is a determinant thus deserves the "det" in front of it (otherwise, it is a matrix)

Comment: One thing is sure: you can check that the solution given in your textbook is exact (no misprinting). But I am not able to find your error.

Comment: Hello thanks i also use undeterminant coefficient by alogx+b and i get the answer $y=x^2(alnx+b)+1/4(lnx+1)$ what is wrong with this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake I see, especially when the homogeneous part is a [Cauchy-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) equation.

---

Note that for a differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)$, we have:
$$W=\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2' \end{vmatrix}\qquad  W_1=\begin{vmatrix} 0 & y_2 \\ f(x) & y_2' \end{vmatrix} \qquad W_2=\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 0 \\ y_1' & f(x) \end{vmatrix}$$
Therefore, your only mistake is that you forgot to divide your ODE by $x^2$. Hence, we must select $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln{x}}{x^2}$.

---

Hence:
$$u_1'=\frac{W_1}{W}=\frac{\ln{x}}{x^3} \implies u_1=\int\frac{\ln{x}}{x^3}~dx$$
$$u_2'=\frac{W_2}{W}=-\frac{\ln^2{x}}{x^3}\implies u_2=-\int\frac{\ln^2{x}}{x^3}~dx$$

To evaluate these integrals, you can use integration by parts. Assuming you've done everything correctly, substituting into $y_p=u_1\cdot y_1+u_2\cdot y_2$ should give you the solution provided by your book. I tried it, it works.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! For correcting my mistakes, but why i have to divide ODE by $x^2$? Is everytime using wronski, i have to make the equation in the form $y"+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)$ ?

Comment: That is correct. If you want to use the above equations, write your ODE in that form, then apply Variation of Parameters and Cramer's rule.

Comment: Thanks!! But are my y1 and y2 correct? I mean i found y1 and y2  using this equation $x^2y"-3xy'+4y=lnx$ before divide it by x^2?

Comment: Yes, your $y_1$ and $y_2$ are correct. It does not matter whether you find the solution to the homogeneous equation as $x^2y''-3xy'+4y=0$ or as $y''-\frac{3}{x}\cdot y'+\frac{4}{x^2}\cdot y=0$, the solution will be the same. The fact that you selected $f(x)=\ln{x}$ is the only mistake I see in your working.

Comment: thankyou so much!! so in conclusion every time i use wronski and cramer i have to make the equation in the form $y′′+p(x)y′+q(x)y=f(x)$ ?? and i think if im using variation parameter also has to be in the form of $y′′+p(x)y′+q(x)y=f(x)$ right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to apply the above equations for $W_1$ and $W_2$, you should do that.

Comment: okay i got it!! can i ask again you said  $x^2y''-3xy'+4y=0$ and $ y''-\frac{3}{x}\cdot y'+\frac{4}{x^2}\cdot y=0$ has the same particular solution, do you find the particular solution by using quadratic equation and remembering the solution? for example if it is repeated root and its euler the solution will have $ln$ like $y_p=Ax^2\ln(x)+Bx^2$. i mean is it better to use $x^2y''-3xy'+4y=0$ or $ y''-\frac{3}{x}\cdot y'+\frac{4} {x^2}\cdot y=0$ ?

Comment: You can use any of them, though I personally prefer to use the form $x^2 y''-3xy'+4y=0$. Though it is still possible to use it on $y''-\frac{3}{x}\cdot y'+\frac{4}{x^2}\cdot y=0$. Using the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$, we obtain:
$$\lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}-\frac{3}{x}\lambda x^{\lambda-1}+\frac{4}{x^2}\cdot x^{\lambda}=0 \iff (\lambda^2-\lambda-3\lambda+4)x^{\lambda-2}=0$$
Since $x^{\lambda-2}\neq 0$, we have:
$$\lambda^2-4\lambda+4=0 \iff (\lambda-2)^2=0$$
This gives the solutions $y_1=x^2$ and $y_2=x^2\ln{x}$ due to the repeated root.

Comment: If you were to use the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$ on $x^2y''-3xy'+4y=0$, you'd obtain the following instead: $$(\lambda^2-\lambda-3\lambda+4)x^{\lambda}=0$$
However, that does not matter, since $x^{\lambda}\neq 0$, giving the same quadratic equation, and thus the same solution.

Comment: ok!! here  $y1=x^2$ and $y_2=x^2\ln{x}$due to the repeated root. i mean here you get $\lambda =2$ then plug it to $yp=Cx^{\lambda} l+C2x^{\lambda} lnx$ , so you have to remember this solution right? and do you always use ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$ ? i see some problem that use $y=e^{\lambda x}$ ?

Comment: You don't have to remember it, though it may be useful to do so. You can derive $y_2$ using [reduction of order](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx), given that you have $y_1$, or you can substitute $t=\ln{x}$ whilst solving the homogeneous part to obtain a second order homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients.

Comment: Ok can you explain where to substitute $t=\lnx{x}$? and here you use ansatz to find one solution right? Is it possible to use $y=e^{\lambdax}$? I mean do you guess it? Thanks!!

Comment: See *"Solution through change of variables"* on the following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation#The_equation).

Comment: thanks so much!!! So i think we always assume $y=x^m$ to find the root. Many thanks!!!!!

Comment: yes i think so!! Thanks for correcting and answering my question also!!!! ^^